# Como recuperar el valor de un método promise

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, polymer

Tengo este un método en la cual realiza una validación de email, pero me recupera solamente `undefined`. No se cual seria la solución para que me devuelva `true` o `false`.

```
....
if (!that._getUserUid(_data[2], company.owner)) {
  console.log(company.owner);
  partialErrors = partialErrors + " [" + headers[2] + "] " + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " es incorrecto, sólo válido <email@domain.com> | ";

}           
....

 _getUserUid: function (_email, _owner) {
   var result = false;
   firebaseApp.database()
      .ref("roles")
      .orderByChild("email")
      .equalTo(_email)
      .on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
        this._owner = snapshot.key;
        console.log("valor es: " + this._owner);
        result = snapshot.key !== null;
      });
```

Comment: No acabo de enteder el código: ¿Dónde está la promesa?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente la petición a firebase no retorna una promesa, no recibe un callback ni menos retorna un valor, sino que se comporta como un EventEmitter.

Dicho lo anterior, cuando invocas un método sobre el objeto firebase, este responderá emitiendo un evento, el cual escuchas con

```
firebase
  .blabla(...)
  .on('evento', function(resultado) {
      ...hago algo con el resultado...
   });
```

Si tú quieres que esto se comporte como una promesa, tendrías que envolverlo en un constructor de promesa (voy a evitar el uso de `arrow functions sólo por si estás usando una versión que no soporta ES7):

```
 _getUserUid: function (_email, _owner) {
   var _this=this;
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

       var result = false;
       firebaseApp.database()
          .ref("roles")
          .orderByChild("email")
          .equalTo(_email)
          .on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
            _this._owner = snapshot.key;
            console.log("valor es: " + this._owner);
            result = snapshot.key !== null;
            resolve(result);
          }).on('error', function(err) {
            reject(err);
          });
   });
});
```

Si te fijas le añadí un listener para la emisión de un error porque si es un EventEmitter debiera tener un evento para ello, y si no lo tiene el simple hecho de escucharlo no hace daño.

Pasado ese punto, ahora volvemos al problema inicial: quieres saber si el owner de una compañía existe o no. En ese caso en vez de:

```
if (!that._getUserUid(_data[2], company.owner)) {
  console.log(company.owner);
  partialErrors = partialErrors + " [" + headers[2] + "] " + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " es incorrecto, sólo válido <email@domain.com> | ";

}
```

Debiera ser algo como:

```
that._getUserUid(_data[2], company.owner)
   .then(function(hasOwner) {
     if(hasOwner !== true) {
       console.log(company.owner);
       partialErrors = partialErrors + " [" + headers[2] + "] " + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " es incorrecto, sólo válido <email@domain.com> | ";

     }
});
```

Sería todo un poco más claro si pudieras usar async/await y arrow functions, pero espero haberte dejado bien encaminado.

## **EDIT**: Gracias a [Nery Ortez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92764/nery-ortez) que me indicó que sí se podía obtener una promesa de firebase, me puse a leer la documentación y encontré este link:

[Keeping our Promises (and Callbacks)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html)

Volviendo al código antes mostrado, una vez que tienes la BBDD inicializada y ejecutas una consulta:

```
let bbdd = firebaseApp.database(),
    consulta = bbdd.
          .ref("roles")
          .orderByChild("email")
          .equalTo(_email);
```

La consulta es un EventEmitter que, como su nombre indica, [emite distintos tipos de eventos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types). Puedes suscribirte a éstos usando el método `on`. Puedes suscribirte a distintos eventos y hacer algo cuando se produzcan:

```
let bbdd = firebaseApp.database(),
    consulta = bbdd.
    .ref("roles")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(_email);

consulta
    .on('child_moved', (snapShot) => {
        console.log('child_moved: ', snapShot.val());
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error en child_moved ', err)
    })
    .on('child_removed', (snapShot) => {
        console.log('child_removed: ', snapShot.val());
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error en child_removed ', err)
    })
    .on('child_changed', (snapShot, prevChildKey) => {
        console.log('child_changed: ', snapShot.val());
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error en child_changed en child_changed ', err)
    })
    .on('child_added', (snapShot) => {
        console.log('child_added: ', snapShot.val());
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error en child_added ', err)
    })
    .on('value', (snapShot) => {
        console.log('value: ', snapShot.val());
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error en value ', err)
    });
```

Pero en este caso tú querías obtener simplemente un dato de una consulta, usando el evento `child_added` que según la documentación:

> A diferencia de value, que permite obtener todo el contenido de la
>   ubicación indicada, child_added se activa una vez por cada campo
>   secundario y cada vez que se agregue un nuevo campo secundario en la
>   ruta especificada.

Ese evento, en conjunto con el uso del método `once` te permitiría obtener el primer resultado de la consulta:

```
consulta    
    .once('child_added', (snapShot) => {
        // el primer resultado está en snapShot
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error en child_added ', err)
    });
```

**Si no le pasas un callback ni un errorcallback al método, entonces acabas de generar una promesa**:

```
let consultaPromise = consulta.once('child_added');
```

En tu caso, aparentemente quieres saber si existe un cierto correo en la colección. En caso afirmativo, asignar la propiedad `owner` de tu clase y en otro caso, añadir un dato a una propiedad que contiene los errores (?)

Entonces:

```
_getUserUid: function (_email) {

    return firebaseApp.database()
        .ref("roles")
        .orderByChild("email")
        .equalTo(_email)
        .once('child_added')
        .then((snapShot) => {
            let valor = snapShot.val();
            return valor.key;
        });

}


... y en otra parte de la clase...

_getUserUid(_email)
  then((_owner) => {
     if(_owner!==null) {
       this.owner = _owner;
     } else {
        partialErrors = partialErrors + .... ; 
     }
  })
  .catch ((err) => {
       partialErrors = partialErrors + .... ; 
  });
```

Comment: *"Aparentemente la petición a firebase no retorna una promesa, no recibe un callback ni menos retorna un valor, sino que se comporta como un EventEmitter."* Firebase **SÍ** acepta `callback`s en el método `on()` y **SÍ** retorna `Promise` por medio del método `once()`.

Comment: Gracias a tu comentario estuve leyendo y es cierto, [al usar el método `once` puedes elegir si pasarle un callback o no pasarle nada y tratarlo como una promesa](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html). Pero me parece importante explicar la diferencia conceptual: Un eventemitter no acepta un callback **como parámetro**. Tampoco **retorna** una promesa ni un valor. Sólo devuelve la instancia misma del emitter. Esa instancia expone métodos y mediante ellos te puedes suscribir y recién a esas suscripciones pasarle callbacks o tratarlas como promesas.

Answer (score -1):

Estás confundiendo algunos conceptos aquí.

Primero que todo recuerda que estás haciendo un trabajo "asíncrono", o sea que no se completa en el momento. Vos llamás a firebase y tenés que esperar que te responda, unos milisegundos, pero tenés que esperar. Con eso en mente revisa:

**Existen funciones `callback`** (también conocidas como "funciones de devolución de llamada"):

> [Son] funciones que se pasan a otra función como un argumento, que
>   luego se invoca dentro de la función externa para completar algún tipo
>   de rutina o acción.

Son funciones en las que vos decís: "Se que lo que estoy haciendo no va a terminar en este momento, pero por favor, cuando terminés hacé esto que te estoy dando en el callback`

En el caso de tu código, esto es lo que tenés, un callback.

```
_getUserUid: function (_email, _owner) {
   // Función externa
   var result = false;
   firebaseApp.database()        // Notá también que no estás devolviendo nada
      // ....
      .on("child_added", function (snapshot) { 
        // Función callback que se va a ejecutar cada vez que se agrege un hijo.
        this._owner = snapshot.key;             
        console.log("valor es: " + this._owner);
        result = snapshot.key !== null;
      });
      // Para el momento en que la función externa termina, el callback no se ha llamado aún
      // 'result' sigue siendo 'false'
}
```

Pero otra vez: No te sirve de nada porque no estas devolviendo nada. La función externa termina. Al rato se llama al `callback`, pero ya no te sirve de nada cambiar el valor de `result`.

Tu otra opción es devolver a `result`. Tampoco te sirve de nada: Función externa termina => se devuelve `result` ..... tiempo después => callback es llamado.

---

**Existen las `Promise`:** que son objetos como callbacks, pero estos se van a cumplir o rechazar. Es una mala definición en realidad, pero cumple con lo que necesitás entender aquí.

En estás vos decís: *"Lo que estoy haciendo no va a terminar ya. Pero me voy a llevar tu promesa de que se cumpla el trabajo"*

En ese caso tenés que buscar que [metodos de firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) aceptan callbacks y cuales devuelven una promesa. El método [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query?authuser=0#once) devuelve una promesa.

Las `Promise` tienen dos métodos: 1) `then` (`entonces`) para cuando se cumple la promesa; y 2) `catch` para cuando la promesa no se pudo cumplir.

En tu codigo esto puede ser conveniente, porque podés devolver la promesa para donde necesites la respuesta. Pero recuerda que la respuesta sigue envuelta en una `Promise`. Te explico:

```
_getUserUid: function (_email, _owner) {
   // Función externa
   return firebaseApp.database()        // Devolvemos la promesa
      // ....
      .once("child_added")
      .then( function (snapshot) { 
        // Función interna que se ejecutará cuando la promesa se cumpla
        this._owner = snapshot.key;             
        console.log("valor es: " + this._owner);
        var result = snapshot.key !== null;
        return result; // Este es el resultado que estará envuelto en la Promise
      });
}
```

Y en tu otro código algo como:

```
!that._getUserUid(_data[2], company.owner).then(result => {
  if (resuelt) {
     console.log(company.owner);
     partialErrors = partialErrors + " [" + headers[2] + "] " + "'" + _data[2] + "'" + " es incorrecto, sólo válido <email@domain.com> | ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda valiosa, estaba confundiendo conceptos, lo probare y les comento y otra vez gracias

Comment: Esta bien. Comentame si te sirve. Aunque estoy viendo desde otra de tus preguntas que tu código es un poco complicado. Además no sé quien marcó como inútil mi respuesta xD

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, podés marcarla como aceptada ;)